# Programming interface for Android Hierarchy Viewer

Tags: android, user-interface, robotium

I try to record my UI states as my application is running. I can use robotium to go through the UI, but I wish I can have a programming interface like Hierarchy Viewer tool, which could provide me the attribute of the UI at the specific timepoint. Any comment is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since Hierarchy Viewer is open source, you can poke around at its code and try to work out some sort of quasi-API. Since your approach will be unsupported, though, it is possible that occasionally you will have to revisit your work and update it to take into account new changes to `adb` and so forth.

Comment: Do you know where can I find the code of Hierarchy Viewer? Thanks!

Comment: @David: I don't see where it is browseable online (courtesy of the kernel.org hack from last year), so you may be stuck with downloading everything from http://source.android.com.